# React hook or function, which one I should use?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Say I am using `format.js`, I could have 2 way to get message string:

```
const getMessage = (intl) => {
  const message = intl.formatMessage({
    id: 'message'
  });
  return message;
}
const MyComponent = () => {
  const intl = useIntl();
  const message = getMessage(intl);
  ...
}
```

or

```
const useMessage =  = () => {
  const intl = useIntl();
  const message = intl.formatMessage({
    id: 'message'
  });
  return message;
}

const MyComponent = () => {
  const message = useMessage();
  ...
}
```

So which way is more recommended in React? and Why?

Comment: Tbh this is more like "what's your preference" than "what do you recommend", My preferred way would be the second one as you don't have to call useIntl and pass it on the function.

Comment: For the second way, What if I also need to call `useIntl` in MyComponent also? and from my understanding the first way will create a function every time component get rendered. So I think it should have some differences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rule of thumb: Use the simpler method and worry about optimiztion later.

But if you need optimization try using a `useMemo`

```js
const message = useMemo(() => {
    const intl = useIntl();
    const message = intl.formatMessage({
        id: messageId
    });
    
    return message;
}, [messageId]);
```

Put it in a custom hook if you need to reuse it. But if you want even more optimization, just cache the messages in a dictionary.